# How to find and exec with or

Tags: bash, find

I am trying to find files with `*.c` and `*.h` extensions. I use the following command

```bash
find "$path" -type f -iname "*.c" -o -iname "*.h" -exec ls {} \;
```

This only executes ls the `*.h` matches. I have tried `-o -iname *.c -o -iname *.h` same thing happens. I would like to execute on both c and h files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to group the disjoint clauses:

```
find "$path" -type f \( -iname "*.c" -o -iname "*.h" \) -exec ls {} \;
```

Without that, `find` interprets your command as two disjoint sets of clauses: `-type f -iname "*.c"` on one hand, and `-iname "*.h" -exec ls {} \;` on the other. That’s why you only see `*.h` matches.

Incidentally, there’s not much point in running `ls` like that; you might as well use

```
find "$path" -type f \( -iname "*.c" -o -iname "*.h" \) -print
```

(but perhaps `ls` is a placeholder).

You can also simplify your command by combining the two globs:

```
find "$path" -type f -iname "*.[ch]"
```

(relying on the default `-print` action).

Comment: They could perhaps also consider using `-iname "*.[ch]"`?

Comment: @steeldriver And they need to ask themselves if they really have files ending in `.C` and `.H` that they need to handle, or they could just switch to `-name`.

Comment: @Kusalananda Or even `-name '*.[chCH]'`